# @: does not work to repeat the :qa command

Tags: command-line, vim-windows, repeated-commands

I open the diff files between 2 code revisions using `git difftool`. I can use `:qa` to close the current diff and go to the next one. Rather than pressing `:qa` repeatedly, I would like to use `@:`, but I get an error `E30: No previous command line` when I try this. I want to know if there is some way to get `@:` working in this case.

Comment: Use [this](https://github.com/balki/vimtabdiff) instead of default git difftool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "colon" register tracks last command typed during current session. As you type `:qa` to quit from Vim, you cannot reuse it later.

So you need to do something else. Maybe create a mapping, maybe store your command in one of "letter" registers, maybe just hit "colon" and then "arrow up", etc. That's the matter of your personal preference.

Comment: Is that true even if viminfo saves registers?

Comment: (From testing, it appears the answer is "yes, it is true," but I'm surprised. This isn't mentioned in the help.)

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Only 0-9, a-z and "minus" are saved. Also, "slash" (though it is a slightly different story) and "unnamed" (which is just the pointer w/o real contents). Other registers are never saved by Vim and this is kind of expected. Though maybe it deserves a direct note in help.